# Couldn't find box selection in Jdeveloper

Tags: selection, jdeveloper

I wonder if there is a **box selection** option in **JDeveloper**.

I first used it in Visual Studio and loved it, then actually suprised to find it in Eclipse, 
but i couldn't find it in JDeveloper. I'm not sure that it's the right place to ask but i appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called Block Selection in **JDeveloper** and it's under

**Upper Menu -- > Edit -- > Block selection**

Comment: That's what happens when you ask something about JDeveloper. You talk to yourself.